# lisp apply append

Tags: lisp, append, apply

i worte this function to remove numbers from a list x

```
(defun rm-nums (x)
  (cond
    ((null x) nil)
    (t (mapcar 'numberp x))))
```

however when i enter `(rm-nums '(32 A T 4 3 E))`
returns `(T NIL NIL T T NIL)`

i want it instead of returning T or Nil, i want it to return the values that caused NIL only [which are not numbers]
so this example should return `(A T E)`
i am supposed to use mapcar WITHOUT recursion or iteration or the bultin function "remove-if"

i think it is related to something called apply-append but i know nothing about it. any help?

Comment: `numberp` is a predicate to test if something is a number, which is why you get a list of `t` and `nil`.  Look for `remove-if-not` in the [Lisp Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/index.htm).

Comment: i know numberp but i forgot to mention i am not supposed to use the built-in "remove-if" function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your course had *this* in mind:

```
(defun my-remove-if (pred lst)
  (apply #'append (mapcar (lambda (x)
                            (and (not (funcall pred x))
                                 (list x)))
                          lst)))
```

It does use `apply` and `append` and `mapcar`, like you said. Example usage:

```
(my-remove-if #'numberp '(32 a t 4 3 e))
=> (a t e)
```

---

More idiomatic solution suggested by Rörd:

```
(defun my-remove-if (pred lst)
  (mapcan (lambda (x)
            (and (not (funcall pred x))
                 (list x)))
          lst))
```

Comment: The effect of the combination `(apply #'append (mapcar ...))` is also achieved by the standard function `(mapcan ...)`. (Well, it's actually more like `(apply #'nconc (mapcar ...))`, but as long as you return only newly created lists from the function passed to it, that will be OK.)

Comment: @Rörd I added a `mapcan`-based solution. You're right, in this case all lists are either freshly-allocated or nil.